# text change event in ATL c++

Tags: c++, atl

I have handle of a text box and want to trigger an event in ATL c++ on any text change in text box.

Answer (score 1):

[ATL 3.0 Window Classes: An Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260759%28VS.60%29.aspx) is one of the best introductory articles for ATL Windowing system.

Having read that then [EN_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761676%28VS.85%29.aspx) notification should point you in the right direction.